# Выборка с помощью DBLookupComboBox

Tags: delphi, база-данных

Всем привет. Вопрос вот какой.

На форме имеется таблица. В ней выводится строка Название из таблицы Ингредиенты,Количество и Дата из таблицы Затраты. таблицы Связаны так Ингредиенты.ID_I:=Затраты.ID_IZ.

Я хотела сделать выборку из таблицы, которая на форме, через DBLookupComboBox. Ну чтобы в нем выбирался ингредиент и соответственно затраты только по нему показывались в таблице.
поскольку это связанные таблицы, пробовала через простое подключение этих таблиц, точнее DataSet-ов к DBLookupComboBox, но добилась только вывода в DBLookupComboBox все ингредиентов и вывода в нем выбранного в таблице ингредиента. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

А разве для этого не используется ADOTable ?
Вы ставите условие, и выводите результат в DBLookupComboBox